# Wait-free put, get data-structure

Tags: data-structures, concurrency, lock-free, wait-free

I am considering concurrent multi-producer multi-consumer data structure that has two methods: `success = try_put(elem)` and `success = try_get(&elem)`. I assume that this data structure has a fixed amount of preallocated memory and in case it is full or empty, `success` boolean flag contains `false` meaning that the corresponding operation can't be made.

The data structure doesn't enforce any ordering guarantees, so it doesn't matter is it a stack, queue, or something else. Does this data structure has some name in the literature?

Is it possible to make the wait-free implementation of this data structure? Does the presence of constant time atomic operations is required, if yes how they should be used?

Comment: What is _wait-free_? If the same `elem` is accessed by 2 threads, the accesses are serialized. Is this a _wait_?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I am using definition of wait-free from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm

Answer (score 4):

The data structure could be named depending on how you implement it.

| Producer | Consumer | Reference | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Multi | Single | [Jiffy: A Fast, Memory Efficient, Wait-Free Multi-Producers Single-Consumer Queue](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.14189) | Queue |
| Multi | Multi | [A scalable multi-producer multi-consumer wait-free ring buffer](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2695664.2695924) | Ring buffer |
| Single | Multi | [FFQ: A Fast Single-Producer/Multiple-ConsumerConcurrent FIFO Queue*](https://www.computer.org/csdl/pds/api/csdl/proceedings/download-article/12OmNxH9XgT/pdf) | Concurrent FIFO Queue |

*  Wait-free interface for producers, Lock-free for consumers